# Loop through a range to execute countif function

Tags: vba, excel, loops, countif

I have some data in my active workbook's *sheet number 3*. *Column A* contains unique value. I want to count the number of times each values exist in *Column A*.

I have written the following code but something is horribly wrong with my logic. Please help me to sort out the issue.

```
Sub cuntef()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Activate
    For i = 2 To 13

         ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = _
             Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _
             (ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i), ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i))

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If column A contains *unique values* as you say, why do you want to count them? ;)

Comment: @Rory1: Value exists multiple times, so i need to count it and then remove duplicate values.

Comment: I was being facetious. You said they were unique values, when clearly they are not.

Comment: I had chosen wrong word i think....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
Sub cuntef()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(13, "A"))
        For Each Cell In Rng
            Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Application.CountIf(Rng, Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no need to loop. Try this:

```
Sub marine()
    With Thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("C2:C13")
        .Formula = "=COUNTIF(A$2:A$13,A2)"
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to add the Count to Column C from row 2 to Last, then the following will do that for you:

```
Sub foo()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C" & LastRow) 'amend this range to apply formula to.

rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-2],RC[-2])"
'rng.Value = rng.Value 'uncomment this line if you want to get the value in the cell and not the formualt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion (LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)  to use dynamic range instead of static. Used LastRow in @L42 logic and it worked pretty well.